# ElasticSearch startup failed

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I startup ElasticSearch:

```
..\elasticsearch-1.3.2\bin>elasticsearch -verbose
```

And see error below:

```
[Loaded org.elasticsearch.ExceptionsHelper from file:/C:/ElasticSearch/elasticsearch-1.3.2/lib/elasticsearch-1.3.2.jar]

{1.3.2}: Startup Failed ...

\- ChannelException[Failed to create a selector.]

        IOException[Unable to establish loopback connection]

                ConnectException[Connection refused: connect]
```

I have tried using the default ports (above) as well as custom ports as below:

```
..\elasticsearch-1.3.2\bin>elasticsearch -Des.http.port=9202 -Des.transport.tcp.port=9303
```

However, still seeing the same error for startup ElasticSearch.

Has anyone had the same problem and found how to resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Did you try port 9200?

Comment: I have tried port 9200 (both leave it as default and added the port to command  line) but still seeing the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue on my local laptop. I have SOCKS Client software installed and it was enabled, which

causes "IOException[Unable to establish loopback connection]".

After disabled SOCKS Client, I was able to startup ElasticSearch again.